# Как сделать прелоадер с изменением размера и цвета кругов

Tags: javascript, css3, html5, svg, css-animation

Нужен такой анимационный прелоадер, который будет работать пока будет отправляться и обрабатываться запрос.

[image: прелоадер]

Пытался найти в интернете подходящий по макету - не нашел.
Можно сделать кодом или gif.

Comment: На [loading.io](https://loading.io/spinner/custom/199362) не нашли ничего подходящего?

Comment: Нет пока не нашел. Там есть такие которые начинают свой радиус с нуля, а мне нужно такие которые начинают свой радиус с 4px и переливаются в другой цвет. И еще там не бесплатно )

Comment: Смотри в сторону @keyframes

Comment: С SVG я практически дел не имею. Поэтому, при своих, мягко говоря, скудных знаниях, могу предложить только [такой вариант](https://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/2xcrs3yb/1/). Минусы при значениях в пикселях очевидны, но раз вы на этом делаете акцент, то возможно вам это подойдёт.

Comment: Deonis, а как для анимации мне передать два параметра? То есть чтобы изменялся не только размер кружочков но и цвет.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Варианты с CSS

Цвет фона и кружков прелоадера подберите по своему вкусу

**Анимация 10 кругов**

```css
body {
  background-color: #1d1f20;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-content: space-around;
}

.sk-wave {
  width: 240px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.sk-wave .sk-circle {
  background-color: #337ab7;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius:50%;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation: sk-wave-stretch-delay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
          animation: sk-wave-stretch-delay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.sk-wave .sk-circle-1 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.2s;
          animation-delay: -1.2s;
}

.sk-wave .sk-circle-2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.1s;
          animation-delay: -1.1s;
}

.sk-wave .sk-circle-3 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1s;
          animation-delay: -1s;
}

.sk-wave .sk-circle-4 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.9s;
          animation-delay: -0.9s;
}

.sk-wave .sk-circle-5 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.8s;
          animation-delay: -0.8s;
}

.sk-wave .sk-circle-6 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.7s;
          animation-delay: -0.7s;
}

.sk-wave .sk-circle-7 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.6s;
          animation-delay: -0.6s;
}

.sk-wave .sk-circle-8 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.5s;
          animation-delay: -0.5s;
}

.sk-wave .sk-circle-9 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.4s;
          animation-delay: -0.4s;
}

.sk-wave .sk-circle-10 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.3s;
          animation-delay: -0.3s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sk-wave-stretch-delay {
  0%, 40%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.4);
            transform: scale(0.4);
   opacity: 0.4; 
  }

  20% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
   opacity: 1; 
  }
}

@keyframes sk-wave-stretch-delay {
  0%, 40%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.4);
            transform: scale(0.4);
   opacity: 0.4;
  }

  20% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
   opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='sk-wave'>
    <div class='sk-circle sk-circle-1'></div>
    <div class='sk-circle sk-circle-2'></div>
    <div class='sk-circle sk-circle-3'></div>
    <div class='sk-circle sk-circle-4'></div>
    <div class='sk-circle sk-circle-5'></div>
    <div class='sk-circle sk-circle-6'></div>
    <div class='sk-circle sk-circle-7'></div>
    <div class='sk-circle sk-circle-8'></div>
    <div class='sk-circle sk-circle-9'></div>
    <div class='sk-circle sk-circle-10'></div>
  </div>
```

**Анимация 5 кругов**

```css
body {
  background-color: #1d1f20;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-content: space-around;
}


.sk-wave {
  width: 240px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
 
}
.sk-wave .sk-circle {
  background-color: #337ab7;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius:50%;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation: sk-wave-stretch-delay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
          animation: sk-wave-stretch-delay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.sk-wave .sk-circle-1 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.2s;
          animation-delay: -1.2s;
}
.sk-wave .sk-circle-2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.1s;
          animation-delay: -1.1s;
}
.sk-wave .sk-circle-3 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1s;
          animation-delay: -1s;
}
.sk-wave .sk-circle-4 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.9s;
          animation-delay: -0.9s;
}
.sk-wave .sk-circle-5 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.8s;
          animation-delay: -0.8s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sk-wave-stretch-delay {
  0%, 40%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.4);
            transform: scale(0.4);
   opacity: 0.4; 
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
   opacity: 1; 
  }
}

@keyframes sk-wave-stretch-delay {
  0%, 40%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.4);
            transform: scale(0.4);
   opacity: 0.4;
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
   opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='sk-wave'>
    <div class='sk-circle sk-circle-1'></div>
    <div class='sk-circle sk-circle-2'></div>
    <div class='sk-circle sk-circle-3'></div>
    <div class='sk-circle sk-circle-4'></div>
    <div class='sk-circle sk-circle-5'></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 12):

### Прелоадер SVG

С помощью SVG довольно легко сделать необычные прелоадеры. 
Ниже пример идущего человечка вдоль пути

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
 <svg width="400px" height="300px" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="www://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="background: #1d1f20;"> 
 <defs>
    <filter 
    id="dropShadow2" 
    x="-20%" y="-20%" 
    width="200%" height="200%">
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1" />
      </filter>
 </defs>
 <!-- Прерывистая линия -->
    <polyline points="100,180 304,180" stroke-width="15" stroke="yellowgreen" stroke-dasharray="5 5" stroke-dashoffset="100"  />
 <!-- Анимация движения человечка вдоль пути   -->
  <g transform="translate(100,170) scale(2,-2)">
    <path stroke="yellowgreen" stroke-width="2"  fill="none" filter="url(#dropShadow2)">
      <animateTransform 
     attributeName="transform" 
  attributeType="XML"
                type="translate" 
  values="0;100" 
  dur="6s"
        begin="0s"
  repeatCount="indefinite" />
   <!-- Анимация фигурки человека   -->
        <animate attributeName="d" begin="1s" dur="0.3s" repeatCount="indefinite"
          values="M-3,0 0,10 3,0 M0,10 0,16 l 4,-5 M0,16 l-4,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0;
                  M 0,0 0,10 0,0 M0,10 0,16 l 0,-5 M0,16 l 0,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0;
                  M-3,0 0,10 3,0 M0,10 0,16 l 4,-5 M0,16 l-4,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0"/>
    </path>
  </g>
   <!-- Анимация текста LOADING   -->
   <text x="150" y="100" font-size="24" font-weight="900" fill="yellowgreen" filter="url(#dropShadow2)" > LOADING
    <animate 
  attributeName="opacity" 
  values="1;0.2;1" 
  dur="3.5s" 
  repeatCount="indefinite" />
   </text>
  </svg>
```

**Вариант с обратным ходом человечка**

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
 <svg width="400px" height="300px" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="www://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="background: #1d1f20;"> 
 <!-- Прерывистая линия -->
    <polyline points="100,180 304,180" stroke-width="14" stroke="#337ab7" stroke-dasharray="5 5" stroke-dashoffset="100" />
 <!-- Анимация движения человечка вдоль пути   -->
  <g transform="translate(100,170) scale(2,-2)">
    <path stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="2"  fill="none">
      <animateTransform 
       attributeName="transform" 
       attributeType="XML"
        type="translate" values="100;0" dur="6s"
        begin="0s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
   <!-- Анимация фигурки человека   -->
        <animate
          attributeName="d" 
          begin="1s" 
          dur="0.3s" 
          repeatCount="indefinite"
          values="M-3,0 0,10 3,0 M0,10 0,16 l 4,-5 M0,16 l-4,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0;
                  M 0,0 0,10 0,0 M0,10 0,16 l 0,-5 M0,16 l 0,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0;
                  M-3,0 0,10 3,0 M0,10 0,16 l 4,-5 M0,16 l-4,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0"/>
    </path>
   <!-- Анимация текста  LOADING  -->
  </g>
   <text x="150" y="100" font-size="24" font-weight="900" fill="dodgerblue"> LOADING
   <animate
    attributeName="opacity" 
    values="1;0.2;1" 
    dur="3s" 
    repeatCount="indefinite" />
   </text>
  </svg>
```

**Вариант с реверсом движения**

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
 <svg width="400px" height="300px" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="www://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="background: #1d1f20;"> 
 <!-- Прерывистая линия -->
    <polyline points="100,180 304,180" stroke-width="10"    stroke="#337ab7" stroke-dasharray="5 5" stroke-dashoffset="100" />
 <!-- Анимация движения человечка вдоль пути   -->
  <g transform="translate(100,170) scale(2,-2)">
    <path stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="1.5"  fill="none">
      <animateTransform 
        attributeName="transform" 
        attributeType="XML"
        type="translate" 
        values="0;100;0" 
        dur="6s"
        begin="0s" 
        repeatCount="indefinite" />
   <!-- Анимация фигурки человека   -->
        <animate 
          attributeName="d"
          begin="1s" 
          dur="0.3s" 
          repeatCount="indefinite"
          values="M-3,0 0,10 3,0 M0,10 0,16 l 4,-5 M0,16 l-4,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0;
                  M 0,0 0,10 0,0 M0,10 0,16 l 0,-5 M0,16 l 0,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0;
                  M-3,0 0,10 3,0 M0,10 0,16 l 4,-5 M0,16 l-4,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0"/>
    </path>
  </g> 
  
   <text x="150" y="100" font-size="24" fill="dodgerblue"> LOADING
   <animate 
    attributeName="opacity" 
    values="1;0.2;1" dur="3s"
    repeatCount="indefinite" />
   </text>
  </svg>
```

**Вариант с реверсным движением полосы загрузки и фигуры человечка**

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
 <svg width="400px" height="300px" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="www://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="background: #1d1f20;"> 
 <!-- Прерывистая линия -->
    <polyline points="100,180 304,180" stroke-width="14" stroke="greenyellow" stroke-dasharray="5 5" stroke-dashoffset="100" > 
 <!-- Анимация движения прерывистой линии -->
 <animate 
   attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" 
   values="0;100;0"
   dur="10s"
   repeatCount="indefinite" />
 </polyline>
 <!-- Анимация движения человечка вдоль пути   -->
  <g transform="translate(100,170) scale(2,-2)">
    <path stroke="greenyellow" stroke-width="1.5"  fill="none">
      <animateTransform
        attributeName="transform"
        attributeType="XML"
        type="translate"
        values="0;100;0"
        dur="10s"
        begin="0s"
        repeatCount="indefinite" />
   <!-- Анимация фигурки человека   -->
        <animate
        attributeName="d"
        begin="1s"
        dur="0.3s"
        repeatCount="indefinite"
        values="M-3,0 0,10 3,0 M0,10 0,16 l 4,-5 M0,16 l-4,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0;
                  M 0,0 0,10 0,0 M0,10 0,16 l 0,-5 M0,16 l 0,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0;
                  M-3,0 0,10 3,0 M0,10 0,16 l 4,-5 M0,16 l-4,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0"/>
    </path>
  </g> 
  
  <text x="150" y="100" font-size="24" fill="greenyellow"> LOADING
   <animate
    attributeName="opacity"
    values="1;0.1;0.1;1;1"
    dur="6s"
    repeatCount="indefinite" />
   </text>
   
  </svg>
```

### Update

**SVG лоадер в виде часов**

```css
body {
 background:black;
 }
.container{
margin:2em;
 width:18vh;
 height:auto;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" id="L2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  viewBox="0 0 100 100" >
<circle fill="none" stroke="cyan" stroke-width="8" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="50" cy="50" r="48" stroke-dasharray="2.12 23"/>
<line fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="cyan" stroke-width="4"  x1="50" y1="50" x2="85" y2="50.5" >
  <animateTransform 
       attributeName="transform" 
       dur="2s"
       type="rotate"
       from="0 50 50"
       to="360 50 50"
       repeatCount="indefinite" />
</line>
<line fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="cyan" stroke-width="4"  x1="50" y1="50" x2="49.5" y2="74">
  <animateTransform 
       attributeName="transform" 
       dur="15s"
       type="rotate"
       from="0 50 50"
       to="360 50 50"
       repeatCount="indefinite" />
</line>
</svg>
</div>
```

**SVG лоадер в виде полярных координат**

```css
body {
 background:black;
 }
.container{
 width:15%;
 height:15%;
 margin:5rem;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container" >
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  viewBox="0 0 100 100" >
  <path fill="greenyellow"  d="M31.6,3.5C5.9,13.6-6.6,42.7,3.5,68.4c10.1,25.7,39.2,38.3,64.9,28.1l-3.1-7.9c-21.3,8.4-45.4-2-53.8-23.3
  c-8.4-21.3,2-45.4,23.3-53.8L31.6,3.5z">
      <animateTransform 
         attributeName="transform" 
         attributeType="XML" 
         type="rotate"
         dur="2s" 
         from="0 50 50"
         to="360 50 50" 
         repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </path>
 <path fill="greenyellow" d="M42.3,39.6c5.7-4.3,13.9-3.1,18.1,2.7c4.3,5.7,3.1,13.9-2.7,18.1l4.1,5.5c8.8-6.5,10.6-19,4.1-27.7
  c-6.5-8.8-19-10.6-27.7-4.1L42.3,39.6z">
      <animateTransform 
         attributeName="transform" 
         attributeType="XML" 
         type="rotate"
         dur="1s" 
         from="0 50 50"
         to="-360 50 50" 
         repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </path>
 <path fill="greenyellow" d="M82,35.7C74.1,18,53.4,10.1,35.7,18S10.1,46.6,18,64.3l7.6-3.4c-6-13.5,0-29.3,13.5-35.3s29.3,0,35.3,13.5
  L82,35.7z">
      <animateTransform 
         attributeName="transform" 
         attributeType="XML" 
         type="rotate"
         dur="2s" 
         from="0 50 50"
         to="360 50 50" 
         repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </path>
</svg> 
  </div>
```

**Ещё вариант прелоадера SVG в виде индикатора зарядки**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width='200' height='200' viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <g id="battery">
      <path d="M65,19v-6c0-3.3-2.7-6-6-6H41c-3.3,0-6,2.7-6,6v6H65z" fill="#10004f"/>
      <path d="M76,17H24.1c-2.3,0-4.1,1.8-4.1,4v70c0,2.2,1.9,4,4.1,4H76c2.3,0,4-1.8,4-4V21C80,18.8,78.3,17,76,17z M72,29v54v4h-4.3 H32.4H28v-4V29v-4h4.4h35.3H72V29z" fill="#10004f" />
     </g>
      <rect x="35" y="72" width="30" height="10" fill="#00e62c">
          <animate 
              attributeName="opacity" 
              from="0" to="1" 
              dur="1s" 
              repeatCount="indefinite" 
              values="0;0;1;1" 
              keyTimes="0;0.1;0.3;1"/>
      </rect>
      <rect x="35" y="58" width="30" height="10" fill="#00e62c">
          <animate 
              attributeName="opacity" 
              from="0" 
              to="1" 
              dur="1s" 
              repeatCount="indefinite" 
              values="0;0;1;1" 
              keyTimes="0;0.3;0.5;1"/>
      </rect>
      <rect x="35" y="44" width="30" height="10" fill="#00e62c">
          <animate 
              attributeName="opacity"
              from="0"
              to="1"
              dur="1s" 
              repeatCount="indefinite" 
              values="0;0;1;1" 
              keyTimes="0;0.5;0.7;1" />
      </rect>
      <rect x="35" y="30" width="30" height="10" fill="#00e62c">
          <animate 
              attributeName="opacity"
              from="0"
              to="1"
              dur="1s"
              repeatCount="indefinite"
              values="0;0;1;1"
              keyTimes="0;0.7;0.9;1" />
      </rect>
  </svg>
</div>
```

[Источник](https://codepen.io/willianjusten/pen/KMPKpE)

Comment: Лучше бы он обратно ходил... )))  Прикольно бы было..Типа ждет

Comment: @Air Можно и обратно запустить, можно попробовать дорожку заставить двигаться

Comment: ну да...  Фантазия человека  безгранична...

Comment: @air готовы два варианта, сейчас попробую с движением дорожки загрузки

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, а ведь вопрос был о другом Но анимация хороша

Comment: @Arthur на вопрос я ответил полностью в первом ответе CSS, а этот для души, может ещё кому-нибудь понравится, сейчас размещу ещё вариант

Answer (score 7):

Вот мои пару строчек на этот счет:

```js
preload.innerHTML = Array(15).fill(0).map((e,i) => 
  `<span style="--i:${i}"></span>`).join("")
```

```css
#preload span {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #48b;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: size 1500ms infinite linear;
  animation-delay: calc(var(--i) * .1s);
}

@keyframes size {
  30% {transform: scale(1);background: #48b}
  50% {transform: scale(2);background: #11a}
  70% {transform: scale(1);background: #48b}
}
```

```html
<div id="preload"></div>
```

Comment: Здорово, что тут скажешь и вроде всё понятно (+)

Answer (score 2):

SVG вариант

```js
preload.innerHTML = Array(15).fill(0).map((e,i) => `<g transform=translate(${i*9})>
  <circle r=2 fill=#48b style="animation: sc 1.5s infinite ${i*.1}s"></circle></g>`)
```

```css
@keyframes sc {
   30% {transform: scale(1); fill: #48b;}
   50% {transform: scale(2); fill: #24a;}
   70% {transform: scale(1); fill: #48b;}
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox=-5,-5,136,10 width=90vw id="preload"></svg>
```